# UITableView - How can I put strings that share a prefix with a header, inside that header programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

Let's say I got 3 headers - `"A"`, `"B"` and `"C"`.

I have an array of strings like this that changes in name and in quantity all the time -

```
["A 483", "A 736", "B 673", "C 524", "C 245", "C 974"]
```

I want each string in my array that starts with `A` to go under the `"A"` header, a string that starts with `B` into the `"B"` header and so on.

Comment: Use sections for each header.

Comment: @Rahul i forgot to mention that the array of strings can change in name and quantity. i need to do it programmatically.

Comment: There are many, many examples and discussions on this topic.. What have you tried so far, and where are you running into trouble?

Answer (score 2):

Use this (you can put this code in a Playground if you want to see what it does):

```
let nameQuantity = ["A 113", "B 123", "C 133", "D 143", "C 153", "D 163", "B 173", "C 183"]

let lettersToNameQuantity = nameQuantity.reduce([:]) { (result: [String: [String]], next: String) -> [String: [String]] in
    var newResult = result
    if let c = next.characters.first {
        let firstLetter = String(c)
        if let _ = newResult[firstLetter] {
            newResult[firstLetter]!.append(next)
        } else {
            newResult[firstLetter] = [next]
        }
    }
    return newResult
}

let numSections = lettersToNameQuantity.count
let numRowsInC = lettersToNameQuantity["C"]?.count
let rowsInC = lettersToNameQuantity["C"]
let sortedKeys = lettersToNameQuantity.keys.sorted()
```

`lettersToNameQuantity` will look like this:

```
["B": ["B 123", "B 173"], 
 "A": ["A 113"], 
 "C": ["C 133", "C 153", "C 183"], 
 "D": ["D 143", "D 163"]]
```

You can use that to implement your table's data source. The keys won't be in sorted order, so make sure you use `sortedKeys` to figure out which section is which letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your array using Dictionary, then separate them by section in your tableView.

```
func groupedItems () -> [String : [String]]{
        let test =  ["A 483", "A 736", "B 673", "C 524", "C 245", "C 974"];
        var grouped = [String : [String]]();
        for item in test {
            let prefix = item.components(separatedBy: " ")[0]
            //or let value = item (to include the whole string)
            let value = item.components(separatedBy: " ")[1]
            if var list = grouped[prefix] {
                list.append(value)
                grouped[prefix] = list
            } else {
                grouped[prefix] = [value]
            }

        }
        return grouped
    }
```

**USE:**

```
    lazy var grouped : [String : [String]] = self.groupedItems()
    .
    .
    .
    .

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return Array(self.grouped.keys)[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let key = Array(self.grouped.keys)[section]
        let values = self.grouped[key]
        return values!.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return Array(self.grouped.keys).count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        }
        let key = Array(self.grouped.keys)[indexPath.section]
        let values = self.grouped[key]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = values?[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
```

**Result:**

[image]